# Why is this spamming the Welcome message?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const welcomeembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0xfcdb03)
        .setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL)
        .setTitle('Welcome to our Discord! \uD83D\uDC4B')
        .setDescription(member)
        .addField('\u200B', "Please verify yourself in " + member.guild.channels.get('723965000062074990'))
    member.guild.channels.get('723240170329079870').sendEmbed(welcomeembed); 
    });
```

I think I remember it working yesterday but today it started spamming the Welcome message endless times when someone joined.

Comment: With the current code can't really say anything, you will need to show more context code, a quick fix might be `bot.once("guildMemberAdd", ...)`. Another option for debugging is logging `bot.rawListeners("guildMemberAdd")`, https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

Comment: bot.once didn't do anything for me

Comment: What does bot.rawListeners("guildMemberAdd") output?

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const welcomeembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0xfcdb03)
        .setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL)
        .setTitle('Welcome to our Discord! \uD83D\uDC4B')
        .setDescription(member)
        .addField('\u200B', "Please verify yourself in " + member.guild.channels.get('723965000062074990'))
    member.guild.channels.get('723240170329079870').sendEmbed(welcomeembed); 
    });
```

you need to make it into

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const welcomeembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0xfcdb03)
        .setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL)
        .setTitle('Welcome to our Discord! \uD83D\uDC4B')
        .setDescription(member)
        .addField('\u200B', "Please verify yourself in " + member.guild.channels.get('723965000062074990')) 
    });
    member.guild.channels.get('723240170329079870').sendEmbed(welcomeembed);
```

with `member.guild.channels.get('723240170329079870').sendEmbed(welcomeembed);` on the outside of the const statement.
At least I think that's correct, I'm a beginner, but I hope that helps you.

Comment: Not the issue, in the second code welcomeembed is outside of the scope, either way it wouldn't fix the issue.